# Quitar permiso Readonly en carpetas y subdirectorios | Error No such file

Tags: python, windows

Tengo un script para mover los archivos que me interesen de los subdirectorios del directorio que se pasa por argumentos.
El problema es que algunas carpetas tienen el atributo marcado de "Readonly" el problema es que no consigo remover dicho permiso, he probado con `os.chmod(path, stat.S_IWRITE)`
pero no funciona y de hecho me pone que dichos archivos figuran como que no existen, estando las rutas bien, ademas ni siquiera mediante cmd usando `tree /F path` figuran.

La organizacion de ficheros es :

```
D:\DESCARGAS UTRRT\WYNONNA EARP - TEMPORADA 3 [HDTV 720P][CAP.303][AC3 5.1 CASTELLANO][WWW.PCTMIX.COM]
├───Wynonna Earp - Temporada 3 [HDTV 720p][Cap.306][AC3 5.1 Castellano
[www.PCTmix.com]
        *Aqui dentro de este directorio estaria el archivo en cuestion*

└───Wynonna Earp - Temporada 3 [HDTV 720p][Cap.307][AC3 5.1 Castellano][www.PCTmix.com]
```

El path pasado como argumento es `D:\DESCARGAS UTRRT\WYNONNA EARP - TEMPORADA 3 [HDTV 720P][CAP.303][AC3 5.1 CASTELLANO][WWW.PCTMIX.COM]`

Este es el codigo:

```
import os
import sys
import shutil
import re
import stat
from hurry.filesize import size, si

def del_rw(action, name, exc):#Para quitar permiso readonly
    os.chmod(name, stat.S_IWRITE)
    os.remove(name)

if len(sys.argv) !=2:
    print("Error numero incorrecto de argumentos")
    sys.exit()

root = sys.argv[1]
tam = 0
try:
    os.chmod(root, stat.S_IWRITE)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(root):
    for fname in fileList:
        full_path = dirName+"\\"+fname
        if os.path.isfile(full_path):
            print(full_path)
            print("exists")
        else:
            print("no exis")

        if fname.endswith(".rar") or fname.endswith(".zip") or fname.endswith(".mp4") or fname.endswith(".mkv") or fname.endswith(".srt"):
            try:
                shutil.move(full_path, root)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            print("hay")
        else:
            tam += os.path.getsize(full_path)/1048576#B to MB"""
    #if dirName != root and tam < 300:
    #    try:
    #        shutil.rmtree(dirName, ignore_errors=False,onerror=del_rw)
    #    except Exception as e:
    #        print(e)
    tam = 0#Reset"""
```

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\Descargas Utrrt\\Wynonna Earp - Temporada 3 [HDTV 720p][Cap.303][AC3 5.1 Castellano][www.PCTmix.com]\\
Wynonna Earp - Temporada 3 [HDTV 720p][Cap.306][AC3 5.1 Castellano][www.PCTmix.com]\\
Wynonna Earp - Temporada 3 [HDTV 720p][Cap.306][AC3 5.1 Castellano][www.PCTmix.com].mkv'
```

Answer (score 0):

El error que recibes indica que el archivo o directorio al que intentas acceder no existe y esto es así sin lugar a dudas.

> Recuerda proporcionar un ejemplo mínimo verificable del problema para que sea más sencillo poder ayudarte.

Ya hice algunos controles y el siguiente código funciona a pesar de los puntos y paréntesis cuadras que tienen los nombres de las carpetas y el archivo. El problema debe ser que el nombre del archivo supera por mucho el máximo de 59 caracteres que son los permitidos en Windows. Compara el nombre del archivo con la string que usas en el código.

El siguiente código funciona correctamente indicando que tanto el directorio como el archivo existen, (nota que el nombre del archivo es más corto):

```
from os import path

directorio = 'D:\\Wynonna Earp - Temporada 3 [HDTV 720p][Cap.303][AC3 5.1 Castellano][www.PCTmix.com]\\Wynonna Earp - Temporada 3 [HDTV 720p][Cap.306][AC3 5.1 Castellano][www.PCTmix.com]'
archivo = 'Wynonna Earp - Temporada 3 [HDTV 720p][Cap.txt'
directorio_completo = path.join(directorio,archivo)

if path.isdir(directorio):
    print('El directorio existe')

else:
    print('El directorio no existe')

if path.isfile(directorio_completo):
    print('El archivo existe')

else:
    print('El archivo no existe')
```

Aquí te dejo el ejemplo de una forma de modificar las propiedades de archivos y carpetas en Python lanzando el comando `attrib` por medio de la librería `os` después de haber controlado si la carpeta existe por medio de `os.path`. Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
from os import system
from os.path import isdir

directorio="D:\\..."

if isdir(directorio)==1:  # Controla si la carpeta existe
    system(f'attrib -R "{directorio}" > nul')  # Quita propiedad solo lectura
```

Comment: nada, sigue sin remover el permiso, es mas si lo remuevo manualmente, al aplicar y cerrar, vuelvo a comprobar y vuelve a habilitarse, y asi con otras carpetas que descargo

Comment: pero el caso de lo que digo es que ni removiendo segun tu sugeriste el permiso, me sigue ofreciendo el mismo error, es decir no puede mover el archivo por que dice que no lo encuentra, (las rutas esta bien, y el archivo existe)

Comment: entonces el problema son los puntos en los nombre de directorios y archivos?

Comment: aun asi trate las rutas de varias formas , literales en string . Manualmente si ingleso la direccion que me devuelve el error me funciona y llego al archivo, pero mediante python no

Comment: Dichos directorios son producto de descargas de torrent, por lo que son los nombres que traen, de ahi que sean poco comun nombrar asi directorios

Comment: Ya actualicé mi respuesta.

Comment: Tienes razon, el problema creo que es el tamaño de la ruta, mas que por los puntos, gracias, hare un rename del file asi puedo acortar para poder ejecutar mi script para cualquier caso